# Youtube in stream skippable ad does not start and goes to final CTA screen

Tags: youtube, ads

I have a Google Ads campaign of a Youtube video (video in stream skippable) of which all the tests seem correct, but since the result is not being good I have checked how when in the channels chosen as audience is going to advertise this video actually is not seen and goes directly to the final screen with the Youtube CTA.

I would appreciate some guidance as to where the failure may be, I can not find any error in the video, campaign or ads group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with the video origin of the ad as "hidden" it works correctly.